# How good is k-means clustering for fully connected similarity based graph

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, k-means, similarity

I have 62 nodes in a graph and the link between any two nodes is calculated by some similarity score. Thus, I have now a fully connected undirected graph with weights in the range 0~0.5. I want to do clustering on the nodes. How good would it be to do k-means clustering on such a network? Please suggest other algorithms for this purpose that would be helpful in such an adjacency matrix.
Also, what would be the actual significance of such a clustering?

Answer (score 0):

K-means **requires continuous variables**.

Because it needs to compute the *mean*.

There are  plenty of algorithms to try for similarity matrixes. The obvious candidate is HAC. But which works and which doesn't depends on your data and desired outcome - we can't tell. You have the data.